# match a specific string in excel and print those rows using python

Tags: python, excel, csv

i am trying to print values from 4 columns in a excel. i need to match on a particular string in the 4th column and then print only those rows which have that string. (eg: if my 4th column in the 2nd row contains 'Sweet' i will print the entire row)

sample excel:

```
name; number; fruit;  comment
test1 ;1   ;  apple ; healthy
test2; 2;     banana ;sweet and healthy
```

here row2 should be printed

so far i have this , couldn't get to exact way to match string.

```
import gzip
import csv, io

with gzip.open("/test.csv.gz", "r") as file:
      datareader = csv.reader(file)

      included_cols = [9, 10, 11]
      for row in datareader:
        content = list(row[i] for i in included_cols if row[i])
        print content
```

Comment: Your code is not valid Python. Please [edit] your question and fix the indention.

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the fact that you are using a range (9 through 11):

```
with gzip.open("/test.csv.gz", "r") as file: datareader = csv.reader(file)
    datareader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in datareader:
        if 'Sweet' in row[9:12]:
            print(row[9:12])
```

Comment: OK. But why `row[10]`?